# how to set the timer interval for one day in a windows service

Tags: c#, timer

I have created a windows service.In which I have set the timer interval for every one minute and so it was triggering for every minute,. But I need to trigger the same for each day..

You can find the code below where I have set the timer interval in `OnStart()` method..

Code:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        TraceService("start service");

        //handle Elapsed event
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);

        //This statement is used to set interval to 1 minute (= 60,000 milliseconds)

        timer.Interval = 86400000;

        //enabling the timer
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: so what is the problem? is it not working?

Comment: which timer are you using? there are many timers in .NET.

Comment: Might this help you bro' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280566/run-once-a-day

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. `timer.Elapsed` found only in `System.Timers.Timer`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yup.. you are right. Missed :(

Comment: It's almost always better to record somewhere durable (e.g. database, file system, etc) when you last ran and then periodically (but more frequently than once a day) check whether a full day has elapsed and take action. Otherwise, every time your service is restarted, it postpones taking action for a further day - so far more time can elapse before you finally take action.

Comment: @Damith Yes its not working... when I give for 1 minute(60000 milli secs) its working..

Answer (score 5):

This post is quite old but I think it's worth mentioning that instead of using a magic number like 86400000 it's better to use something like new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0).TotalMilliseconds , so that if someone needs to change it they will know what should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

So, couple of things regarding your post:

First, it does not state what is the problem!

Technically, Timer supports a timer interval of about 25 days.
So, your code should work.

If you want to exceed 25 days and you are not concerned about thread safety, I suggest you go to System.Threading.Timer.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624789/maximum-timer-interval)

Since, your service runs as a windows based service, i suggest you go to System.Threading.Timer.

Comment: My question is how to set the timer interval for a day.. When I try giving for a minute(60000 millisecs) its working.. Hence I gave 86400000(24*60*60*1000) as the timer interval which is not working.. I was testing by calling a method which stores the log entries in a seperate file where I am not getting the entries when I check for a a day just by changing the System date time manually... Please provide solution to achieve this...

Comment: @D.N.E.Z - if you tell a timer to wait for a day, it will wait for a day. It doesn't pay attention to the system clock.

Answer (score 0):

In C# now you can use TimeSpan class to get total milliseconds in day to set a per day timer.

```
var totalMilliSecondsPerDay = TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalMilliseconds;
var timer = new Timer(totalMilliSecondsPerDay);
```